# How to create a custom theme for Ant Design (React) in LESS using CodeSandbox?

Tags: reactjs, less, antd, codesandbox

## Environment Setup

For ease of use, I've already completed the following steps: [Here's a link to a sample project](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-leftpad-35ty9).

1. Head to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/) (or use VSCode - making appropriate changes to these steps) and create a new project (I created a Vanilla  project)
2. Add the following dependencies:

   - `antd`
   - `react`
   - `react-dom`
3. Make the following file changes:

#### Update/Create `src/index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.less";
import App from "./App";

const root = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

#### Create `App.js`

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Button>Test</Button>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### Rename/Create `styles.css` to `styles.less`

```
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

---

## Problem

Now reload the codesandbox *Browser* tab for the project. It loads endlessly with the message *Transpiling Modules...* and going to the console shows the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at n (less.js:10831)
```

---

## Ant Design

The Ant Design documentation states the following [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-less-file):

#### Customize in less file

Another approach to customize theme is creating a less file within variables to override `antd.less`.

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; // Import Ant Design styles by less entry
@import 'your-theme-file.less'; // variables to override above
```

Note: This way will load the styles of all components, regardless of your demand, which cause `style`option of `babel-plugin-import` not working.

---

## Question

Is this issue pertaining to the *note* in the Ant Design documentation?

How can I resolve this issue and override the Ant Design styles in LESS?

Answer (score -1):

In your codesandbox env you are not configuring `babel-plugin-import` so having `@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";` in your `.less` file won't make any difference.

Best and quick way to have `ant design` codesandbox env is to fork this codesandbox template.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/wk04r016q8

For your sandbox code to work, you need to configure your parcel bundler to do less compilation to css using `@parcel/transformer-less`

Link: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel#transforms